# Updating each iteration using d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am working on a line graph in `d3.js` and am unsure how to to iterate through each country and update my graph's points. I want to draw each country on my map. In my code I have only hard coded the first country and the output shown in the following images. Have attached my csv file to show the column names. I am unsure whether I need to alter my csv file to do so. 
any help is appreciated

[image: my csv data]

[image: line graph]

```
function init(){

var w = 600;
var h = 600;    
var barPadding = 20;

var dataset;

        var rowConverter = function(d){
            return {
                year: parseFloat(d.year),
                Afghanistan: (d.Afghanistan),
                Albania: (d.Albania),
                Algeria: (d.Algeria),
                Andorra: (d.Andorra),
                Angola: (d.Angola)
        };
    }

    d3.csv("hello.csv", rowConverter, function(data){

            dataset = data;
            if (data==null){
                alert("Error, data has not been loaded!");
            }
            else{
            draw(dataset);
            console.log(dataset);
            }
    });

    function draw(){

    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([d3.min(dataset,function(d){
            return d.year;
        }),
        d3.max(dataset,function(d){
            return d.year;
        })])
        .range([barPadding,w-barPadding]);

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0,100])
        .range([h-barPadding,barPadding*2]);            

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                    .scale(xScale)
                    .ticks(5);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
                    .scale(yScale)
                    .ticks(5);

    var valueline = d3.line()
                    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.year); })
                    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.Afghanistan); });                      

    var svg = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

    svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.year);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.Afghanistan);
    })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill","slategrey")

    svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.year + "," + d.Afghanistan;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.year);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.Afghanistan);
    })
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "10px")
    .attr("fill", "blue");      

    svg.append("path")
        .data([dataset])
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - barPadding) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + barPadding + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);       
    }

 }
 window.onload=init;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a `selectAll(null).data(dataArray).enter()` uses a data array to enter an element for each item in the data array, we need to create an array for each line we wish to enter. Currently you have an array for each year, but we want to enter a path for each data series/country. So we need to create an array where each item in that array represents a path.

This requires altering the structure of our data from:

```
[
  {year: 2000, series1: number, series2: number... },
  {year: 2001, series1: number, series2: number... },
  ....
]
```

To an array with an item for each line:

```
[
  { year: 2000, series1: number },
  { year: 2001, series1: number },
  ...
  { year: 2000, series2: number },
  { year: 2001, series2: number },
  ...
]
```

I'm using this approach because it is commonly seen in d3 cannonical examples such as [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955).

This is relatively easy to do. After we parse in our csv/tsv/dsv with d3, we can access the columns of the dataset with `dataset.columns`. The first column isn't a series we want to plot, it represents the x axis, so we can slice it off with `dataset.columns.slice(1)`. Ok, with the remaining columns we can iterate through each series and create the data array above:

*I'm using csvParse in the snippet, which replicates d3.csv except that it doesn't use a callback function for the returned data, letting me define the dataset with  `var dataset = d3.csvParse(...` rather than `d3.csv("file.csv", function(error, dataset) {...})`*

```js
var csv = "year,series1,series2,series3\n"+
"2000,5,2,8\n"+
"2001,6,4,7\n"+
"2002,9,3,5\n"+
"2003,10,6,7\n"+
"2004,9,7,8"

var data = d3.csvParse(csv);

var series = data.columns                 // get the columns
    .slice(1)                             // drop the first column(years)
    .map(function(series) {               // for each series:
       return  {                          // return a new object:
         series: series,                    // name it
         values: data.map(function(d) {     // get the data:
           return { year: d.year, value: d[series] };
         })
       }
     });
     
console.log(series);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>


<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```

Now we have an item in the data array for each series we want to draw a line for. Now we're cooking with gas. So we can now use `selectAll().data(series)` to enter a line for each item in the data array, creating a line for each series.

*In keeping with Mike Bostock's example I linked to above, I've created an property which identifies which series each item represents, as well as a property which holds the arrays of year/value pairings.*

Here's a quick demo:

```js
var csv = "year,series1,series2,series3\n"+
"2000,5,2,8\n"+
"2001,6,4,7\n"+
"2002,9,3,5\n"+
"2003,10,6,7\n"+
"2004,9,7,8"

var data = d3.csvParse(csv);

var series = data.columns
    .slice(1)
    .map(function(series) {
       return  { 
         series: series,
         values: data.map(function(d) {
           return { year: d.year, value: d[series] };
         })
       }
     });
     
var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([2000,2004]).range([0,500]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,10]).range([300,0]);
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory20);
     
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });
  
d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(series)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("fill","none")
  .attr("stroke", function(d,i) { return color(i) })
  .attr("d",function(d) { return line(d.values) });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>


<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```